# What exactly is added/changed in the Plus version of PSO Ep. 1 & 2?

Tags: version-differences, nintendo-gamecube, phantasy-star-online

For the GameCube there are two versions of PSO Ep. 1 & 2:

- **Phantasy Star Online Episode I & II** (JA/NA 2002 / EU 2003)
- **Phantasy Star Online Episode I & II Plus** (JA 2003 / NA 2004 / no EU release)

What is changed/added in the *Plus* version?

Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Phantasy_Star_Online&oldid=549302861#Releases):

> This version added various quests to Offline Mode that were originally available exclusively to Online Mode, while also fixing certain bugs and exploits that could be used in the previous release, such as being able duplicate various items from one's inventory.

Which quests are these? Which bugs are fixed? Which exploits? *Anything* else (even minor details)?

Comment: Another change not yet mentioned here [in this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PSO/comments/h97061/pso_plus_or_original_gc/fuvk1eh/): "the Photon Blast circle rotates oppose[d] [t]ou non-plus where it doesnt"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Fixed shop dupe (speak to NPC woman in shop area, lure her close to a shop and speak to a shop keeper at the same time to be able to move again with a shop window open, which allows you to use the bank and a shop at the same time, which then allows you to run around with a bank window and inventory open at the same time -> you can deposit and drop items to the floor at the same time).
- Fixed double save save file corruption (occurred when joining a game, destroyed save data sometimes).
- Seat of the Heart, East Tower, West Tower, Central Dome Fire Swirl are available for offline play.
- Ep 2 Challenge Mode is available offline.
- GBA online only minigame downloads in 'The Fake in Yellow' that are already available in the Ep 1 & 2 version such as Chao Garden, Nights Score Attack and Puyo Pop available for offline play.

All in all this is just a bug fix release and makes some online single player content available offline. 
According to vgchartz.com, 450,000 people bought PSO Ep. 1&2 for GC, 150,000 for Xbox. Plus was only available for GC and only 50,000 people bought it (that's 11% of GC players), since it wasn't interesting for online play and the online community was already ruined by the shop dupe.

Comment: I'd also like to add that the Plus version fixed what was at the time, and as far as I know continues to be, the only exploit available to back up and to play back up games on the Gamecube without the addition of a mod chip.